# How to control the raspberry pi over internet using android app?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspicam, internet, pigpio

I had bought a Raspberry pi 3b+ recently to make many of the projects I had dreamed of. Most of these (or maybe all) involves controlling the GPIO pins over the internet using an app.

One of the main project is an RC car which can be operated over the internet. The car is 1500 miles away at my home. The reason for me to choose an app (not website) to control is that I need to press and hold the 'button' so that the car would move as long as i hold the 'button' and stop when i take my finger off the 'button'. I found a way to stream the videos over the internet on a website. But no good way to control the car. The car has been set up decently and i can control the car over bluetooth without any problems.

All I want to have is 4 buttons on the app which tells my car to move forward, backward, turn left and turn right. I don't need a feedback from my Raspberry pi, or any other commands that would slow the data send across my phone and pi. I want the command to be sent as quickly and short as possible. No security measures required as this is a very 'homely' project. I plan to use a portable hotspot in the rc car to get my pi connected to internet to make it very mobile (I don't mind going for boosting my home's wifi signal if the hotspot idea is having any problems).

Please help me out! Figuring out a solution for this would enable me to make all the other projects possible.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you'd need to write some *programs* .. what programming languages are you proficient in?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

i am not good at programming, but i have figured out so far from other projects that i see online how to input certain commands. is there a very simple coding to just instruct 4 commands to the raspberry pi?

Comment: depends on what programming language you want to code in

Comment: any language is fine. please advice me which language, software or method I should be using for this purpose.

Comment: "No security measures required" - are you quite sure? Someone will hack your RPi, set it up as a proxy for cashing out stolen credit cards or selling drugs, then you'll have a long talk with the police about that "homely" project of yours.